# add css to JavaScript Popup box

Tags: javascript, xml, css, html

i have made a js popup box to verify customers age before enter to a category.

i made a `age-verification.js` file with this code included, in my templat `js/` folder:

```
var agePrompt=prompt("What is your age?");

if (agePrompt>=18) alert('Welcome!')
else {
alert('Sorry! Come back in a few years!')
document.location=" ";//link if not 18

}
```

and i added this XML code:

```
<reference name="head">
     <action method="addItem">
          <type>skin_js</type>
          <name>js/age-verification.js</name>
     </action>  
</reference>
```

to

```
Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Categories -> {Selected category} -> Custo Design -> Custom Layout Update
```

> now i want to add some css styles to my js popup window.

how to do that? (with details please)

Comment: You cannot. alert() simply shows a native message box, so it'll look however the OS makes it look. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565035/how-to-create-and-apply-css-to-javascript-alert)

Comment: @dh47 i know i should do it with html. but i don't know how.
i will thankful if some one explain it for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can add with below code for css in skin folder

```
<reference name="head">
 <action method="addItem">
      <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/styles.css</name>
  </action>    
</reference>
```

and if want to create custom popup you can use

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653238/custom-popup-boxes-in-html-javascript-and-css

Comment: are you sure ?? so you mean to say we can apply styles to alert messages?? @liyakat

Comment: @dh47 as i understood from question, he has  made a js popup box as custom.

Comment: that mean you didn't understood the question he just added `alert('Sorry! Come back in a few years!')` alert messages and `css` cannot be added to alert messages moreover your answer is not at all related to his question.

Comment: but if he will make popup with custom html and instead of alert() he can use custom alert. at that time above code will utilize.

Comment: @dh47, i am agree with you that we can not change color for popup which used function like `prompt`